# How can I efficiently call an external Python script that needs to run continuously?

Tags: memory, external-calls, python

I am writing a Mathematica program that tries to run 100+ Python programs, via `StartProcess[]`, continuously. It seems to work when I run < 100 programs, but, at the current number of 500 programs that I am attempting to run, my computer crashes every time.

Is what I am trying to accomplish realistic? And, if so, is there another way I can run these scripts that will not crash my computer?

Thanks!

Here is the code:

```
(*This function takes in the creatureFolder pathway and starts the \
AlpacaInterfacer.py application*)
executePythonFile[creatureFolder_] := Module[{process},
  process = StartProcess[$SystemShell];
  (*Change the directory to the current one*)
  WriteLine[process, StringJoin["cd ", creatureFolder]];
  (*Execute the file*)
  WriteLine[process, "AlpacaInterfacer.py"];
  ]
```

And I am running `executePythonFile[]` in a Table, where the Python scripts' locations are saved to a list, so that the same program will not be started twice.

Comment: Why not just use `subprocess` within python to manage this? Seems simpler. Also why not use `ExternalEvaluate`/`StartExternalSession`?

Comment: I think StartExternalSession might be what I was looking for! What would the differences be between StartExternalSession and StartProcess, in terms of memory usage? Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure if memory is your issue so much as having a whole pile of open processes running. The CPU isn't really designed to have so many processes. A better way to do this is probably using `threading.Thread` within python, assuming each process itself isn't terribly memory hungry. Otherwise create a `multiprocessing.Pool` object to process your inputs. As I noted, the process management should really be on the *python* side, rather than trying to fake something yourself.

Comment: Ok, I will look that up then, thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad to be help. Hopefully you can stave off any further crashes.